# Android SQLite ....no such table:venue (code 1):, while compiling

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Here, I'm trying to fetch data from a pre built SQLite DB.....
I'm picking up code from this website....
   http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Now the problem is I'm ending up with no such table problem...I've already added my table in the assets folder...!

[Screenshot of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxuUL.png)

Here's the DBHelper class

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.prokode.cwg2014/assets/";

private static String DB_NAME = "glasgow.db";

private static final String TABLE_VENUE = "venue";

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
private static final String KEY_CAPACITY = "capacity";
private static final String KEY_GAMES = "games";
private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
private static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
private static final String KEY_GEO = "geo";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;



public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    this.myContext = context;

}
    @Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


//Getting single venue
public VenueInfoDS getVenueInfo(String id) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_VENUE, new String[] { KEY_ID,KEY_NAME, KEY_IMG,
        KEY_CAPACITY,KEY_GAMES,KEY_LOCATION, 
        KEY_LINK, KEY_GEO }, KEY_ID + "=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

VenueInfoDS venueInfo = new VenueInfoDS(cursor.getString(0),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),
        cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7));
// return venueInfo
return venueInfo;
}

//Getting All venues
  public List<VenueInfoDS> getAllVenueInfo() {

List<VenueInfoDS> venueInfoList = new ArrayList<VenueInfoDS>();
 // Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_VENUE;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
 // looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        VenueInfoDS venue = new VenueInfoDS();
        venue.set_id(cursor.getString(0));
        venue.set_name(cursor.getString(1));
        venue.set_img(cursor.getString(2));
        venue.set_capacity(cursor.getString(3));
        venue.set_games(cursor.getString(4));
        venue.set_location(cursor.getString(5));
        venue.set_link(cursor.getString(6));
        venue.set_geo(cursor.getString(7));
        // Adding contact to list
        venueInfoList.add(venue);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
//return venueInfo list
return venueInfoList;
 }

//Getting venues Count
public int getVenueInfoDSCount() {
 String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_VENUE;
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
 cursor.close();

 // return count
 return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

Here's My Fragment Class....

```
 public class VenueInfoFragment extends Fragment {
String title, capacity, games, location, image;
TextView venueTitle, capacityValue, gamesValue, locationValue;
ImageView venueImage;
DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
VenueInfoDS venueInfo;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout fragmentLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.venue_info_fragment, container, false);

    return fragmentLayout;
}


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    venueTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_venueTitle);
    capacityValue = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_capacityValue);
    gamesValue = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_gamesValue);
    locationValue = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_locationValue);
    venueImage = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_venue);
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());

    venueInfo = dbHelper.getVenueInfo("even1");

    title = venueInfo.get_name();

    venueTitle.setText(title);



}

}
```

LOG CAT----

```
 07-22 19:22:20.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-22 19:22:20.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:      no such table: venue (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, img, capacity, games,  location, link, geo FROM venue WHERE _id=?
 07-22 19:22:20.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
 07-22 19:22:20.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):    at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
```

Answer (score 0):

That `DB_PATH` variable is not used anywhere. Android has no knowledge of the existence of a database in your assets folder. Instead it creates a new one inside of `/data/data/<your.package.name>/databases/` and expects you to create the schema and populate it with data. That's how `SQLiteOpenHelper` works.

To use an existing database, you need to copy the database from your assets folder to your app's internal data directory on the device before trying to use the database. The tutorial you linked to does not show how to do this. Something like this library might be more appropriate:

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper